# sort by date with aggregate request in mongodb is not sorting properly

Tags: mongodb, mern

I'm trying to get the sum or records by groping its created date. Following is how the date looks in DB `date:2022-05-18T22:16:59.864+00:00`

My NodeJs/Express Code is as follows

```
const totalClicks = await StatModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { campaign_id: id } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
]);
```

And following is the output

```
[{"_id":"2022-05-17","count":20},{"_id":"2022-05-15","count":9},{"_id":"2022-05-19","count":37},{"_id":"2022-05-18","count":12}]
```

Comment: while grouping u convert the date into `_id`. So use  `{ $sort: { _id: -1 } }`, instead of  `{ $sort: { date: -1 } },`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @varman your solution worked. Following is the updated code.

```
const totalClicks = await StatModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { campaign_id: id } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
]);
```

Comment: I prefer `{ $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "day" } }` (if using MongoDB 5.0 or newer) rather than by string

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and update the answer with your solution also.